How to install a self-built driver on Windows 10 without enabling testsigning mode?
I am building Virtualbox Guest Additions to run on a virtual machine (including creating and installing some drivers on Windows).
Testing in testsigning mode has been successful, but when I disable testsigning, I encounter the error 'Windows cannot verify the digital signature for this file. A recent hardware or software change might have installed a file that is signed incorrectly or damaged, or that might be malicious software from an unknown source.'
Although my .exe, .sys, .cat, and .dll files are all properly digitally signed (purchased from Globalsign), when I check using the signtool /verify command, no errors are reported. (Test install on Windows 10 22H2)
What steps need to be taken to install these drivers in the Guest Additions on Windows without encountering the above error?
Do I need to follow the testing steps according to the Hardware Lab Kit guidelines and submit the results to Microsoft for certification?
Thanks
when I check using the signtool /verify command, no errors are reported

Done.
Just download the cross certificate file from the EV Code Signing Certificate document and add the file path to VBOX_CROSS_CERTIFICATE_FILE and VBOX_CROSS_CERTIFICATE_SHA2_FILE
